# Предложение "Это её шаль, а не/ни_кого другого", как правильно пишется и почему?

Tags: орфография

Предложение "Это её шаль, а не/ни_кого другого", как правильно пишется и почему?

Answer (score 2):

Никак не правильно. "Оба хуже". Это предложение не совсем по-русски оформлено, отсюда проблемы.

Союз **а** в сочетании с "никого" не может быть противительным без каких-то дополнительных слов.

Возможны варианты:

*Это её шаль, ***(и) никого*** другого.*
*Это её шаль, а ***не кого-то*** другого.*

Первый вариант, кстати, тоже немного неряшлив стилистически. Но это ошибка совсем другого уровня. Второй - полностью нормативен.

Answer (score 0):

Предложенный в первом ответе вариант корректный: *Это её шаль, а не **кого-то другого**.*

1. Выбор отрицательной частицы НЕ (а не усилительной частицы НИ) соответствует противительным отношениям, на что указывает союз А. Другой возможный вариант: *Это её шаль, а не чья-либо еще.*
2. Нельзя сказать: *Это её шаль, а не кого другого*. **Ошибка** связана с  тем, что слово "её" может быть **притяжательным** местоимением (ее шаль), а может быть формой **личного местоимения:** увидел ее.
3. Сочетание "**а не кого другого**" используется в следующих примерах:

Или для того, чтобы покупатель верил, что он покупает кролика, **а не кого** другого? [Маша Трауб.  (2008)]

...Бобка сразу понял, что фея Мая не обманула его и что он видит ее, **а не кого другого** в лице этого необыкновенного китайца. [Л. А. Чарская. (1907)]